# Bound mismatch in Java for generic method

Tags: java, generics

I can't understand why I'm getting this compilation error

> Bound mismatch: The generic method `element(T)` of type `Resource` is not
>   applicable for the arguments (`Class<Chassis>`). The inferred
>   type `Class<Chassis>` is not a valid substitute for the
>   bounded parameter `<T extends Resource>`.

with the following code:

```
public class Resource {
    protected abstract class has<T extends Resource> {
        public has(T v) {}
    }

    protected <T extends Resource> has element(T v) {
        return new has<T>(v) {};
    }
}

class Car extends Resource {
    has chassis = element(Chassis.class);
}

class Chassis extends Resource {
}
```

Why is this invalid? `Chassis` extends `Resource`, so why doesn't match to `<T extends Resource>`?

And how could I constraint element() method to accept as an argument a Resource class object or any Resource subclass object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Chassis.class` is an instance of `java.lang.Class`, which only extends `java.lang.Object`.

The `<T extends Resource>` expects an actual instance of `Resource` (or one of its subclasses).

To solve this, you can change your method declaration to the following:

```
protected <T extends Resource> has element(Class<T> v) {
    return new has<T>(v) {};
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I added another question which is, how to accomplish the expected behavior then?

Comment: I believe changing the method declaration to `element(Class<T> v)` should do the trick.